# how prevent cordova to accept self-signed ssl certificate

Tags: android, cordova, ssl

How to make the cordova hybrid android app to throw a proper error and capture it, when it is trying to access a self-signed https URL.

In my mobile, without any warning/error it goes through a self-signed https URL. In what case this might happen.

Is it happening based on a cached SSL certificate?

Will cordova automatically accept self-signed ssl as default?

If yes, how to disable self-signed certificated being accepted?

Comment: SSL checking is disabled when you install the app in debug mode, once you create the signed .apk and install it, self signed certificates won't work.

Comment: It should work if you do this https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#CustomTrust but until now I wasn't able to get it work